# NoReverseMatch Error in Django, can't pass id parameter

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm trying to learn python / django but I keep running into this error when I try to add the ability for someone to be able to reply to an already existing entry on a website. It looks like I'm not passing anything for a parameter in a view but I can't figure out why as this same structure worked for another project I was doing from a book. (fyi this is my first post here, I've read a ton of other posts on this here and elsewhere and none of them have helped so far, sorry if any of this is dumb).

Here's the error:
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /instructors/instructors/1/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'new_inquiry' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['instructors/new_inquiry/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

`urls.py`: I'm getting the error from the last one, the 'new_inquiry' view url, but am including all just in case something could be related

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'instructors'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('instructors/<int:instructor_id>/', views.inquiry, name='inquiry'),
    path('instructors/new_instructor/', views.new_instructor, name='new_instructor'),
    path('new_inquiry/<int:instructor_id>/', views.new_inquiry, name='new_inquiry'),
]
```

`views.py`: Issue is with the new_inquiry function (I think). I just can't get it to pass the instructor_id parameter for some reason...

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Instructors
from .forms import InstructorForm, NewInquiryForm

def index(request):
    instructors = Instructors.objects.order_by('created_date')
    context = {'instructors': instructors}
    return render(request, 'instructors/index.html', context)

def new_instructor(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = InstructorForm()
    else:
        form = InstructorForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_instructor = form.save(commit=False)
            new_instructor.save()
            return redirect('instructors:index')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'instructors/new_instructor.html', context)

def inquiry(request, instructor_id):
    inquiry = Instructors.objects.get(id=instructor_id)
    inquiries = inquiry.instructorinquiries_set.order_by('-inquiry_date')
    context = {'inquiry': inquiry, 'inquiries': inquiries}
    return render(request, 'instructors/inquiries.html', context)

def new_inquiry(request, instructor_id):
    instructor = Instructors.objects.get(id=instructor_id)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = NewInquiryForm()
    else:
        form = NewInquiryForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_inquiry = form.save(commit=False)
            new_inquiry.instructor = instructor
            new_inquiry.save()
            return redirect('instructors:inquiry', instructor_id=instructor_id)

    context = {'instructor': instructor, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'instructors/new_inquiry.html', context)
```

Templates:

`inquiries.html`: The template that includes link to the form template. I get the error when I try to visit this page.

```
<p><a href="{% url 'instructors:new_inquiry' instructor.id %}">Add new inquiry posting</a></p>
```

`new_inquiry.html`: the form template

```
<form action="{% url 'instructors:new_inquiry' instructor.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button name="submit">Add inquiry</button>
</form>
```

Note: as I've been messing around I found that if I replace 'instructor_id' with just an integer for the parameter like this `<p><a href="{% url 'instructors:new_inquiry' 1 %}">Add new inquiry posting</a></p>` it will let me go to the page and then will allow me to go to the form and fill it out and everything works, but obviously that won't work as it will send the form contents to whatever id is listed there, not the appropriate id.

I won't include the models unless someone asks for them as this post is already really long, but in case it's relevant there are two models - 'Instructors' and 'InstructorInquiries'. InstructorInquiries contains the foreign key of 'Instructors'.

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: You haven't added "instructor" to the context in your `inquiry` view. Since "instructor" is not found "instructor.id" is returning an empty string

Comment: Thank you - I just ended up changing the href to look for the inquiry id from the `inquiry` view and that worked but only knew to try that from your comment. Now I'm getting an integrity error when I try to submit the form at the `new_inquiry` view :/ (I know that's a separate issue from my post)

Comment: In case anyone else sees this and cares - the integrity error I was getting was because I had an extra 's' in the `new_inquiry` view where I had `new_inquiry.instructors` instead of `new_inquiry.instructor`